# How to make a URL link like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello please guys am creating a blog and I want my blog blink to be like this of stackoverflow shown like this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php
```

Instead of it being like this

```
http://stack overflow.com/questions.php?tagged=php
```

Comment: You can do some research on `.htaccess`. You will find a lot of tutorials on how to create clean urls.

Comment: You can do some research on `mod_rewrite` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: I thought .htaccess is used to restrict users from visiting limited sites?

Comment: @HorlarME, .htaccess is just a file that contains the commands that you want your Apache server to execute.

Comment: Here's a good place to start:  http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls,  and you should read a little here about semantics as well:  http://phoboslab.org/log/2008/04/what-s-wrong-with-clean-urls